# Are C strings guaranteed to be arrays?

Tags: c++, c, string

Are C strings (as opposed to `std::string`) guaranteed to be implemented as arrays? For example, say, I have

`char const * str = "abc";`

What it boils down to is whether or not `str + 4` a legal pointer value (without dereferencing that is). I'm asking this because I dont know if C strings are a special case due to the null character terminating it.

Comment: `str + 4` is guaranteed to be a legal pointer value, but it is not guaranteed to be dereferenceable.

Comment: Because C strings exist in C++...

Comment: @ildjarn what if you go out of your memory space. As in this string is stored at the very end of the memory for this process would it still be a valid pointer?

Comment: @twain249 : Yes, both C and C++ guarantee that C-arrays and C-strings always have a legal one-past-the-end value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First part of the question**

> *Are C strings guaranteed to be implemented as arrays?*
>
> *For example, say, I have:* `char const * str = "abc"`

Yes, a string object is of an array type. A character string is a data format and a (character) string object is of a type `array` of `char`.

In your example `str` points to the string literal `"abc"`. Character string literals have the type `char[N+1]` where `N` is the length of the string (i.e., the number of characters excluding the terminating null character).

Some references from Standard and K&R 2nd edition:

C defines a string literal as:

> (C99, 6.4.5p2) "A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz"."

and says (emphasis mine):

> C99, 6.4.5p5) "For character string literals, the **array** elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence;"

K&R 2nd edition says:

> "Technically, a string constant is an **array** of characters"

and

> "when a string constant like `"hello\n"` appears in a C program, it is stored as an **array** of characters containing the characters in the string and terminated with a `'\0'` to mark the end."

**Second part of the question**

> *What it boils down to is whether or not str + 4 a legal pointer value (without dereferencing that is).*

Yes, it is a valid pointer. In your case `str + 4` is a pointer one past the last element of the array.

A valid pointer is a pointer that is either a null pointer or a pointer to a valid object. For an element of an array object, a pointer one past the last element of the array object is also a valid pointer.

Note that for the purpose of the last rule ("the one past element"), for pointers to objects that are not elements of an array, C treats the object as an array of one element.

> (C99, 6.5.6p7) "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Comment: In fact, `&"string"` has type `char (*)[7]` (pointer to array 7 of char) because of the array nature of string literals.  A whole lot of compilers used to get this wrong, back in the day.  Not sure if some still do...

Comment: @torek I use the words *"pointer to a string"* as defined in  the C Standard *(C99, 7.1.1p1) "A pointer to a string is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character"* even if of course a pointer to an array `N` of char is of type `char (*)[N]`.

Comment: Yes, "pointer to string" is a fine way to describe what you get when you write the string literal without a leading `&` address-of operator.  I'm just noting that strings are *so* "arrayish", as it were, that you can take their address, just as if you had done: `const char String[7] = "string";`.  (Also, it's worth noting that despite the lack of `const` in the result type of `&"string"`, the literal itself is, at least in principle, read-only.  This rather awful glitch in C's type system is due to historical accident.)

Comment: @torek by the way, if I can say this here, thank you for all your posts in clc. Your posts have been a **huge** source of inspiration and knowledge for many of us.

Comment: +1, but I wish you had kept using the denomination "legal pointer" instead of switching to "valid pointer" towards the end, since “valid pointer” is more or less implicitly defined to mean "dereference-able" by 6.5.3.2:4 and attached footnote 87 in C99.

Comment: @PascalCuoq actually I use the denomination of *"valid pointer"* as does the Rationale (C99) document (and btw as does H&S reference book too). Here what is in the Rationale: *"Implicit in the Standard is the notion of invalid pointers. In discussing pointers, the Standard typically refers to “a pointer to an object” or “a pointer to a function” or “a null pointer.” A special case in address arithmetic allows for a pointer to just past the end of an array. Any other pointer is invalid."*

Answer (score 3):

They are guaranteed to be a contiguous sequence of `char`s. If that's your definition of an array, then yes.

In your example you will have 4 chars, one for each character and one for the null terminator. `str+4` will be out of range.

Comment: I got stumped typing "contiguous", getting red squigglies. You beat me to the answer thanks to that, but otoh I learned to spell contiguous :)

Comment: @Tobias, when I first saw the word I thought it was a misspelling of "continuous". But that was a very long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

> Are C strings guaranteed to be implemented as arrays?

With a wide definition of *array*, yes, they are a contiguous sequence of chars with a terminating null character.

> What it boils down to is whether or not str + 4 a legal pointer value

The literal (`"abc"`) is an array stored somewhere in the process memory. The type is is `const char[4]` (in C++, I am not sure if in C it is `char[4]`). Then `str` is a pointer to the first element of the string literal, and the expression `str+3` is correct, can be dereferenced and the pointed character will be 0. The expression `str+4` is a pointer beyond the end of the array and cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, I had an off-by-one error that I corrected. I am assuming that you are referring to the original answer.

Comment: `char[4]` in C indeed (without the `const`)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, they are, <strike>but str+4 isn't necessarily a legal pointer as 1 char may not be equal to 1 byte.</strike>

Comment: Heh, no problem. The info is corrected, no need for downvote. :)

Comment: @Tobias `sizeof(char)` is guarantee to be 1. (Byte is not necessarily 8 bits, but char is always a byte).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that :) But how does that work with 7-bit bytes (rare these days, I know, but they were around), when the length of a char HAS to be at least 8 bits?